# Place UIToolBar above UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I'd like to place a UIToolBar above a UISplitViewController but Interface Builder will not let me do so (using the standard split view template as a start). I know I can implement different tool bars in each of the two views within the UISplitViewController, but I want one seamless bar that lies outside the frame/bounds of the controller, directly above it and right under the status bar. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by the `UISplitViewController`. If you need this sort of UI you would typically create a custom setup to achieve this.

I'd construct a setup using two `UINavigationController`s that are controlled using my App Delegate and just take it from there. There will be some extra work for you, handling rotation, but that's to be expected when doing custom stuff.

This shouldn't be *too* hard.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is exactly what I did. I create my own version of the UISplitViewController. I'm glad I did too because there are other limitations to the stock UISplitViewController that would have cause major problems in my project.